# Converting a Unix timestamp to an SQL timestamp in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timestamp, date

I have passed the result of `Date.now()` and other plain Unix timestamp values like `1534360109480` into SQL and ran them through this:

`"@converted_date" = to_timestamp("@date") AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';`

And it consistently returns `50591-11-28 22:32:38`.

I do not understand how the year could possibly be 50591 and the date/time is not accurate beyond that anyways.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would help to know the type and content of `@date`...

Comment: @stickybit Either Date.now() or a unix timestamp, like I said at the beginning of the post

Comment: It makes no sense to feed the result of `now()` into `to_timestamp()`

Comment: "`Date.now()`" or "a unix timestamp" are no specific values and leave a lot of room for interpretation. E.g. I suppose `Date.now()` refers to any OO language, but which? Please show actual values **as the database sees them** or at least elaborate on how and in which environment you pass the values, so that people familiar with that environment may deduce the values, that reach the DBMS.

Comment: I think I am personally confused in the use of terminology. Date.now() in JS. I want a unix string like `1534360109480` to be converted to something like `2018-08-15 18:20:30` in UTC

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`to_timestamp` accepts the epoch value ("Unix time") with second precision, while your value seems to have millisecond precision. You need to do something like

```
to_timestamp(@date/1000) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
```

Comment: How can I exclude the "second" ?
Above code gives me "2022-11-17 06:27:15" and I want to remove second

Comment: You seem to have a different question @KavehNaseri, so please ask one.